# Generic makefile showing no rule to make target error

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I wrote a makefile to compile and link all the files in my project. Right now i only have 2 cpp files: `src/main.cpp` and `src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/ssb_main.cpp`.

My makefile content is :

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/*.cpp) 
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix bin/obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
DEBUG_OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix bin/debug/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
CC_FLAGS := -I${PWD}

main.out: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES)

bin/obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
g++ -c -o $@ $< (CC_FLAGS) -w
```

But when i do a make it gives the error :

> make: *** No rule to make target `bin/debug/ssb_main.o`, needed by `main.out`.  Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: your pattern rule is expanded as follows for the object files in `DBEngine`

```
bin/obj/ssb_main.o: src/ssb_main.cpp
```

You can see how that won't work I'm sure.

You can add another pattern rule to fix it

```
bin/obj/%.o: src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/%.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $< $(CC_FLAGS) -w
```

A simpler method however is to mirror your source and build trees and use `vpath`, make sure there is a directory called `DBEngine/benchmark/ssb` in the makefile directory as well, and use the following:

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/*.cpp) 
OBJ_FILES := $(CPP_FILES:src/%.cpp=%.o)
CPPFLAGS  := -I${PWD}
CXXFLAGS  := -w

vpath %.cpp src

main: $(OBJ_FILES)
```

The built-in rules will handle the rest.

Side notes: `-I${PWD}` is superfluous, and `-w` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the compiling rule you have specified that the source files are in the 'src' directory. But from your description it seems that the ssb_main.cpp file is in the 'src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/' folder, so *make* does not find the dependency to compile ssb_main.o.

You can use variable VPATH to specify the folders where make should look for your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have sub-folder is your src folder you can try to use

```
CPP_FILES := $(shell ls -pR ./src | grep -v /)
```

It will list all cpp files under src and its sub-folders excluding . and .. .

Comment: Hi, ls -A -R src/*.cpp is unable to find src/DBEngine/benchmark/ssb/ssb_main.cpp file

Comment: I slightly modified the ls command. It should now list all the files in the src folder and sub-folders